# Inno Setup: Add button action for skipping to next page

Tags: inno-setup

In an Inno Setup installer, I need a separate custom button to mimic the behavior of clicking the next button, is their a function I can apply to the OnClick handler of the custom button to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can trigger the next button's `OnClick` event manually for instance this way (the only parameter here is the `Sender`, which is usually the object which triggered the event, but in the original next button click event handler is this parameter ignored, so let's pass an empty, `nil` object there):

```
WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick(nil);
```

So the rest is about creating your own button and calling a code like above to mimic the next button click, for example:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
procedure MyNextButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick(nil);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  MyNextButton: TNewButton;
begin
  MyNextButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  MyNextButton.Parent := WizardForm;
  MyNextButton.Left := 10;
  MyNextButton.Top := WizardForm.NextButton.Top;
  MyNextButton.Caption := 'Click me!';
  MyNextButton.OnClick := @MyNextButtonClick;
end;
```